# How to get current cursor as Texture2D Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem, I want to get the current cursor, and get it as a texture2D in Unity.

When I say current cursor, I mean the current cursor the user has got. For example, if the user changes his cursor to a cat, I want to have the same cat cursor in Unity.  That is the reason why I don't just search online for the default cursor.

I have tried to search in google for this, but all I got is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918990/c-sharp-capturing-the-mouse-cursor-image) , it was posted in 2009, and the code doesn't work(it says "Handle doesn't represent a ICON" if you were wondering).

Comment: Show us your code, what have you tried yourself?

Comment: @MeanGreen Well, i really don't know where to start. But as i said in my question, I have searched in google, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918990/c-sharp-capturing-the-mouse-cursor-image) was the only result i could find, and i tried Tarsier answer, and it makes a "Handle doesn't represent a ICON" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys, but i figured it out,i found out about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351872/how-to-convert-cursor-to-imagesource) and used SepehrM answer to convert the cursor to bitmap, and just [used this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40482700/convert-a-bitmap-to-a-texture2d-in-unity) to convert the bitmap to a texture2D, Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

Well the steps to follow that comes to my mind are:

1. Check what cursor is active in Windows
2. Read that image as a texture in Unity
3. Apply the texture to the cursor

The problem I see is this will change from OS to OS, so it will be hard for you to make it compatible with all Operative System.

I wasnt able to read the current active cursor, so my answer is uncomplete. Maybe someone will be able to complete what is missing:

```
//This is the part I am not sure how to complete
//String currentCursor = 

//Here is where Windows store the cursors, you need to point to the one the 
//user is using
String path = "C:\Windows\Cursors"+currentCursor;

//Here you load that image as a texture
Texture2D cursorTexture = new Texture2D(16, 16);
cursorTexture.LoadImage(File.ReadAllBytes(path));

public CursorMode cursorMode = CursorMode.Auto;
public Vector2 hotSpot = Vector2.zero;

//You apply the texture to the cursor in Unity
void Start()
{
    Cursor.SetCursor(cursorTexture, hotSpot, cursorMode);
}
```

Maybe you can find [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.current(v=vs.110).aspx) how to do the first step using something similar to this, however I don´t know it

Answer (score 1):

Any solution with win32 API would be platform dependend and don't work on another platforms. So you can add your own custom cursor manager.

```
//container for cursor data
[System.Serializable]
public struct CustomCursor
{
    public Texture2D Texture;
    public Vector2 HotSpot;
    public CursorMode Mode;
}

//container for all cursor you used in you project
[System.Serializable]
public class CursorsHolder
{
    [SerializeField]
    private CustomCursor defaultCursor;
    [SerializeField]
    private CustomCursor cursorA;
    [SerializeField]
    private CustomCursor cursorB;
    [SerializeField]
    private CustomCursor cursorC;

    public CustomCursor DefaultCursor { get { return defaultCursor; } }
    public CustomCursor CursorA { get { return cursorA; } }
    public CustomCursor CursorB { get { return cursorB; } }
    public CustomCursor CursorC { get { return cursorC; } }

    public void InitializeDefault(CustomCursor defaultCursor)
    {
        this.defaultCursor = defaultCursor;
    }
}

public interface ICursorHandler
{
    Texture2D CurrentCursor { get; }
    void SetCursor(CustomCursor newCursor);
}

//Manager that cached last setted cursor
public class CursorHandler
{
    private CustomCursor currentCursor;

    public CustomCursor CurrentCursor { get { return currentCursor; } }

    public void SetCursor(CustomCursor newCursor)
    {
        currentCursor = newCursor;
        Cursor.SetCursor(currentCursor.Texture, currentCursor.HotSpot, currentCursor.Mode);
        Debug.LogFormat("{0}", currentCursor.Texture);
    }
}


//Main script for cursor management usage
public class MyScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private CursorsHolder cursorsData;

    ICursorHandler cursorHandler = new CursorHandler();

    private void Awake()
    {
        cursorsData.InitializeDefault(new CustomCursor() { Texture = PlayerSettings.defaultCursor, HotSpot = Vector2.zero, Mode = CursorMode.ForceSoftware });

        cursorHandler.SetCursor(cursorsData.DefaultCursor);     
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            cursorHandler.SetCursor(cursorsData.CursorA);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B))
        {
            cursorHandler.SetCursor(cursorsData.CursorB);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
        {
            cursorHandler.SetCursor(cursorsData.CursorC);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            cursorHandler.SetCursor(cursorsData.DefaultCursor);
        }

    }
}
```

You must not forget assign default cursor in player settings.